# Difference between PhoneGap and Cordova and which one should we install?

Tags: android, eclipse, netbeans, cordova

I have been tasked with developing an Android and iOS application with **PhoneGap** (http://phonegap.com/)

However, as I read, things start to get really complicated: Some people say **Cordova** (http://cordova.apache.org/) is now **PhoneGap**, others say PhoneGap is just a distribution of PhoneGap.I lost 3 days and still can't find a proper way or a guide to install a fully functional PhoneGap plugin either in Eclipse or Netbeans running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

**What I tried:**
1. Installing Eclipse, installing **MDS AppLaud Phonegap Plugin** (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/applaud-phonegap-android-jslintjshint#.Utf1JPiSTh8). This one actually installed at once, and it actually lets me create a new PhoneGap project in Eclipse, however, the I cannot select any SDK different than 4.4. (?!)
2. Installed NetBeans and after I tried to install phonegap and cordove through nodeJS it failed, again.

**My question is:**
Which one I should install and how to do it in Ubuntu, using either Eclipse of NetBeans?!

**Edit**:
OK guys, I just found out how to install nodeJS and PhoneGap on Ubuntu 12.04: http://paste2.org/1OnX6M6F . Still trying to integrate it in some IDE for the real thing, though!

Comment: Cordova is the open source Apache project - anyone can contribute. Phonegap is the downstream distribution of Cordova that Adobe provides. It's the same thing except they change "Cordova" to "PhoneGap" in the documentation. Adobe provides additional services on top, like PhoneGapBuild. Other companies provide other distributions that consume Cordova, like IBM's Worklight. Generally you won't use an IDE to build a Cordova application because it's usually not really needed - you're mostly just doing HTML/JavaScript development, unless you need a custom plugin.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the detailed information. Today I think I finally managed to find a succesful (and EASY!!!) way to run/create PhoneGap applications for Ubuntu. When I got home I will write an answer with a step-by-step guide, including your answer too (with crediting you ofc).

Comment: You can use either cordova or phonegap, the only difference I see is that if you want to be able to use phonegap build, you should use phonegap to create the project. An important point is that once you choose phonegap or cordova to create a project, you have to stick with it when installing plugin or building project.

Comment: And about installing and integrating with eclipse, the documentation about cordova cli or phonegap cli is quite clear and easy to follow. In http://phonegap.com/install/ installing phonegap, creating a new project and running it only takes 4 lines of shell.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, to put it simple:

**PhoneGap** - The original project developed by volunteers

**Cordova** - The Apache's version of Phonegap, which has exactly the same documentation and functionality as the original PhoneGap but is integrated in NetBeans 7.4.

Comment: Are you sure about your answer?
Phonegap is ancestor of Cordova

Comment: First you had only PhoneGap, then it got acquired by Adobe. Adobe decided to split the project up to Cordova and PhoneGap. Cordova and PhoneGap are exactly the same, but PhoneGap is maintained by Adobe and has some extra Phonegap build tools built in. Cordova is not part of Adobe, but from Apache.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to basically start developing an app, I suggest this for PhoneGap:

These are the steps I used to install PhoneGap on Ubuntu.  Take note, this is for PhoneGap version 2.8.1.  *Personally I was not able to get nodeJS to install the latest. If you need the latest to be installed, check around on google.*  Referencing [This tutorial](http://psydrake.tumblr.com/post/39908525042/quick-tutorial-android-phonegap-development-on-linux).

**Step 1**
Install [Java 7 JDK](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

**Step 2**
Install [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

**Step 3**
Download & Extract PG [v2.8.1](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.8.1.zip)

**Step 4**
Download [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

**Step 5**
Set up environment variables

**Step 6**
Create base project

```
./create location/to/put/project package_name project_name
```

**Step 7**
Import Project into Eclipse

- File->New->Android->Android Project From Existing Code
- Browse to where you placed the project and select it

Now you can start developing.

*Reminder: This is the way to do it for v2.8.1 of PhoneGap. Different versions(especially 3.*) will be different (nodeJS)*

Comment: Drew, I just found a workaround how to install Phonegap using nodeJS on Ubuntu. Take a look here: http://paste2.org/1OnX6M6F . Hope it helps you in some other machine or after you reinstall OS some day. :}

Comment: In that case, once you create the project, using `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`, you should just be able to do step 7 and import into Eclipse.  It's also described in more detail in the [documentation guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

Comment: Well, actually I am at this point right now. I will hit you up what's the outcome.

Comment: I can create a project with "phonegap create" but I can't figure out how the HECK I could actually make my phonegap project for a specific platform like Android or iOS. "phonegap install android" errors the following: http://paste2.org/IcIxE3em . And no, the cordova command errors too.

Comment: If you have the android SDK installed, you'll only be able to develop for the Android Phone. As far as I know, to emulate an Iphone, you'll need to install PhoneGap onto a Mac and use the Mac environment.  The `install` command only installs your application after you have developed it(or during development), onto the Phone.

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://docs.phonegap.com. Read the "Overview chapter, then "Platform Guides" and "The Command-Line Interface". Follow the steps and in the end you should be able to build your app. It takes a while but it's worth it.

I havn't integrated cordova/phonegap in my IDE. I just created the app with the command line interface. In netbeans I created a HTML5 project and linked the **app-root/www** directory into this project. I'm programming with Netbeans and building and running the app with the command line interface. That's all.

In order to have some code completion, I have written an extra class (facade) which encapsulates the phonegap code. It just delegates its calls to the phonegap API. That is especially nice if the phonegap API changes as it only affects my code in that particular facade class.

The last thing I want to share: I found out that the build and run process with the command line interface is pretty slow. Executing **cordova prepare android** and then running the android project in Eclipse/ADT is a lot faster.