# using cordova plugin in phonegap

Tags: android, extjs, cordova, ocr

I am working with Sencha Touch 2 + phonega 3 and interested in cordova plugin: http://plugreg.com/plugin/albertarvesu/image-scanner-cordova-plugin How do I make it work with phonegap coz each time I add it, build it, and I get error during compile time errors: 'ant debug -f'. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. One more question, are these plugins interchangeable like use phonegap plugin in cordova and vise-versa?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165478/difference-between-phonegap-and-cordova-and-which-one-should-we-install

Comment: Hi, thanks for the commment,I have followed the link and its shaping my direction. I am still trying to find out the main difference in code between phonegap plugin and cordova plugin...